# C# Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, windows-console

Everything is already setup on the google calendar api (not sure if i configure correctly or i missed something out)
I created a c# console application,that writes an appointment to google calendar.

What i want to achieve is that , i want to get all the user's or subscriber who subscribe to my app, so what i can write
on there calendar if there is an event.

What configuration do i need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is the sample code,

```
GoogleCalendarUtils utils = new GoogleCalendarUtils();
ArrayList months = /* the list of months*/;

//    Update the content window.
foreach( ThistleEventMonth month in months )
{
    foreach( ThistleEvent thistleEvent in month.ThistleEvents )
    {
        utils.InsertEntry( thistleEvent );
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i get the list if users who subscribe my app?

Comment: You have to use Google OAuth 2.0 get the info and then process.

Comment: I already did apply the oAuth 2.0. Question is how do i get the list of subscriber

Comment: In what way does this code " get all the user's or subscriber who subscribe to my app, so what i can write on there calendar if there is an event." (whatever that means) ?

Comment: You cant get all the users all at once. For eg, when a user click on Register the event, at that time we call the api to get the info the user and enter the entry to there calendar, if you want to keep a record of track, you can save the info the user for internal purpose.

Comment: Here is the issue.
1. I have an winforms application an appointment system.I need to sync there appointments on my application to there google calendars account.
So if "Dr. A" has an appointment on May 1, 2016, this one will be written on my application at the same time i need to write this  on the calendar for Dr. A

Comment: Using OAuth2 only its possible.. refer this `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync` Anyway i got down voted wasting time here for this..! But OAuth2 is the one which will help..!

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a multi-domain problem.

Some questions to consider:

1. What calender is it? A public one?
2. How do they subscribe with *your* console?
3. What happens when the software shuts down, crashes, etc?
4. Do you need to know the event *after* it was written to the calendars?
5. If not, do new subscriber get previously added calender entries?

Other than that, you should have a look at [Webclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx). Then we have here the reference for the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/). The main request method you're searching is this one: [Events Insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). With that, we can craft our own inseration variant.

```

```
private readonly List<string> _calendarIDs;
/* lets assume you imported webrequests and you're going to write a method
 * Further we assume, you have a List of calendars as object attribute
 */
public void InsertEntry(DateTime start, DateTime end,
   string title, string description) {
    using(var client = new WebClient()) {
        var epochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["attachements[].fileUrl"] = "";
        values["attendees[].email"] = "";
        values["end.date"] = end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        values["end.dateTime"] = (end - epoch).Seconds;
        values["reminders.overrides[].minutes"] = 0;
        values["start.date"] = start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        values["start.dateTime"] = (start - epoch).Seconds;
        values["summary"] = title; // This is the calendar entrys title
        values["description"] = description;

        foreach(string calendarID in _calendarIDs) {
            var endpoint = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{0}/events", calendarID)

            var response = client.UploadValues(endpoint, values);
            var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    }
}
```

This is a minimal example and the api has a lot of endpoints and parameter. You should have a deep look into it, maybe you find more useful parameter.